# How can you chain F# functions inline properly for a set of operations performed on a list?

Tags: .net, f#

So basically if I have a simple list in F#

```
let ls = [3; 9; 2; 15; 3]
```

And I want to sortDescending and then take 3.  I can do this chaining:

```
let orderList ls = List.sortDescending ls
let take3 ls = List.take(3) ls
let main ls = (orderList >> take3) ls
```

And this works just fine and will work for what I want when using the F# Interactive debugger.  But I am trying to do it inline in all one expression and not getting the syntax right.  Is it possible and I am just not getting the syntax.

```
let main2 ls = List.sortDescending >> List.take(3) ls
```

I am moving from more of an object orient mindset where in C# I can do this:

```
var ls = new List<int>{ 3, 9, 2, 15, 3 };
var subset = ls.OrderByDescending(x => x).Take(3).ToList();
```

And I was just expecting you could chain continue like fluent syntax INLINE, but it appears I am missing syntax or not getting something simple.  I have only been learning F# recently, but so far I dig it.  I just am having a hard time getting my head around some of the way things are chained together.

Comment: Is there some reason why you're not using the forward pipe operator? Perhaps this is one of the syntaxes you're not familiar with yet.  You want `|>`, not `>>`, which is the functional composition operator.

Comment: I tried that and was doing a brute force approach for a while, so I determined I should just ask rather than keep flailing with wrong syntax.  This let main2 ls = List.sortDescending |> List.take(3) ls is what I first tried but obviously the syntax is wrong.  I am just missing some key syntax of knowing how to pass in the resulting object and do similar operations to it.  Just some noob problems not knowing the language fully yet.

Comment: maybe it's not that popular but there exists a fluent library for F#.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The `>>` operator takes two functions and produces a function that is the composition of those two functions.

The `|>` operator takes a value and a function and passes the value to the function, producing another value.

Suppose we have

```
let addone x = x + 1
let double x = x * 2
```

Then `(addone >> double) 100` and `100 |> addone |> double` are both 202. Do you see why? Make sure this is clear.

Think of them like this.  `f >> g` is composition:

```
let compose f g =
  fun x -> g (f x)
```

So

```
(addone >> double) 100
```

is the same as

```
(fun x -> double ( addone x ) ) 100
```

Which is the same as

```
double (addone 100)
```

Whereas `x |> f` is pipe:

```
let pipe x f = f x
```

So

```
100 |> addone |> double
```

is the same as

```
(addone 100) |> double
```

is the same as

```
double (addone 100)
```

In C# the business of chaining together extension methods is basically the pipe operator:

```
customers.Take(100).ToList()
```

is the same as

```
Enumerable.ToList(Enumerable.Take(customers, 100))
```

Comment: Yes I get what you are doing but I am confused when you apply this thinking to a List object.  If I was to do: 'let main ls = orderList |> take3 ls' I keep getting a 'Type mismatch...' error.  So something has to be more explicit or there are more operations to doing collections than doing single base types.

Comment: I got it now I was missing passing the parameter in preceding what I was trying.  So the method could be: 'let main ls = ls |> List.sortDescending |> List.take(3)' while 'let main ls = List.sortDescending |> List.take(3)' would fail.  Or I could just chain it directly as called since it is simple enough 'let result = ls |> List.sortDescending |> List.take(3)'.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I think you get confused because you miss some details about parenthesis in F#. You have written this:

```
let main2 ls = List.sortDescending >> List.take(3) ls
```

I think you probably assumed that `List.take` is called with a single argument, but it isn't. Notice that in F# parenthesis only group things. They are not needed to call a function. In your case your parenthesis has literally no effect. Look at those two function calls. They have the same meaning.

```
List.take (3) (ls)
List.take 3 ls
```

If this confuses you, just think of simple math. Also here parenthesis just group stuff. That means, anything inside of parenthesis is computed first.

```
(3 * 6) + 10
3 * 6 + 10
```

Also in the above case you get the same result, with or without parenthesis. You only need parenthesis if you need another precedence. Like first adding `6 + 10` and then multiply the result by 3.

```
3 * (6 + 10)
```

In F# it is the. Whatever is inside of parenthesis is calculated first. In your above example you just put `3` in it. This has no meaning at all. It would be the same as if you write.

```
(3) * (6) + (10)
```

As another example look at:

```
sqrt(2.0) + 2.0
sqrt 2.0 + 2.0
```

This both example mean the same. And probably that is your confusion. But the right way with parenthesis how it is interpreted is written like that:

```
(sqrt 2.0) + 2.0
```

The first parenthesis around `(2.0)` has no meaning. But if you first want to add the numbers and you want to square-root `4.0` you need to write:

```
sqrt (2.0 + 2.0)
```

Back to your example. If we remove the parenthesis around `3` and adding the necessary parenthesis back to your code how the code is interpreted you actually have written something like this:

```
let main2 ls = List.sortDescending >> List.take(3) ls
let main2 ls = List.sortDescending >> (List.take 3 ls)
```

This means. Your code first executes `List.take 3 ls`. The result of that is a `List`. Then you try to do compose a function `List.sortDescending` with a `List`. This sure fails with a type-error. What you prabably wanted to do is just partial apply `List.take` with a single argument and compose the resulting function with `List.sortDescending`. In this case you need to write:

```
(List.take 3)
```

Or as a full example:

```
let main2 ls = (List.sortDescending >> (List.take 3)) ls
let main2 ls = (List.sortDescending >> List.take 3) ls
```

Both of the two lines above once again have the same meaning. What you do nowin your case is create a partial applied function `List.take 3` and you compose it with `List.sortDescending`. This then returns a new function that you then pass `ls` as an argument. Notice that this code is a little bit verbose. You also "theoretically" could write it just as:

```
let main2 ls = (List.sortDescending >> List.take 3) ls
let main2 = List.sortDescending >> List.take 3
```

Notice that this potentially can create a "Value Restriction" error if you don't call the function with a concrete value. By the way there are still other ways how you can write your function. One way that also eliminates a value restriction error is:

```
let main ls = ls |> List.sortDescending |> List.take 3
```

This is the same as:

```
let main ls = List.take 3 (List.sortDescending ls)
```

Btw. as another notice not directly related to your problem. You also should look at `List.truncate` instead of `List.take`. `List.take` throws an error if it cannot return the exact amount of elements you specified. `List.truncate` never throws an error.

```
List.take     4 [1;2;3] // throws an exception
List.truncate 4 [1;2;3] // returns -> [1;2;3]
```

If you want further details about piping, nesting or composition. I have a blog article covering this details: http://sidburn.github.io/blog/2016/09/25/function-application-and-composition

Comment: Thanks, still learning the syntax and I appreciate the feedback.

Answer (score 1):

You can of course use the linq extension methods in F# as well.

```
open System
open System.Linq


let ls = [3; 9; 2; 15; 3]
ls.OrderByDescending(fun x -> x).Take(3).ToList()
```

Moreover, if you like this type of syntax, [Fsharp.Core.Fluent](http://fsprojects.github.io/FSharp.Core.Fluent/) can do it:

```
#r @"..\packages\FSharp.Core.Fluent-4.0.1.0.0.5\lib\portable-net45+netcore45+wpa81+wp8+MonoAndroid1+MonoTouch1\FSharp.Core.Fluent-4.0.dll"
#r "System.Runtime"
open FSharp.Core.Fluent
open System.Runtime

ls.sortDescending().Take(3).toList()
```

Please note the difference between the `.ToList()`, which is .NET's generic list:
`Collections.Generic.List<int> = seq [15; 9; 3]` and `.toList()`, which is F#'s linked list: `val it : int list = [15; 9; 3]`.

Comment: LOL, good point.  I did not even think to open up more .NET system libraries for added functionality.  I just ASSUMED it had System, System.Linq, System.Text, and System.Collections.Generic like C# usually gives me on .NET 4.6.1.  I will have to remember that for future use that LINQ by default is not on.

Comment: @djangojazz yes, usually you would either use the various [Seq Module](https://msdn.microsoft.com/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/collections.seq-module-%5bfsharp%5d) (or List) functions or [query expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/fsharp/language-reference/query-expressions) to express what Linq does. Or rather Linq is one implementation of functional syntax in C#/.NET.